# Laravel 5: Validating Edits In-Place

Tags: ajax, validation, laravel-5

I had previously asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43432975/laravel-5-4-in-place-editing-with-ajax) in regards for setting up in-place editing with Laravel 5 and AJAX. I hadn't updated it because I had managed offline to figure out what was wrong with it.

While the table is capable of editing user rows in-place, I'm now trying to add validation on top of it, intending on utilizing Laravel's built-in validator. However, for some reason it doesn't seem to be working. When I try to pass in the failed validator back through the JSON, it spits out every possible error I'm checking for. It's as if the validator is treating every input as empty, which doesn't make sense, as the rest of the function is clearly taking in the inputs as intended.

The code snippets in my previous question are still mostly relevant, but there have been updates to **HomeController.php**, as can be seen below:

```
public function updateTable(Users $users){

    $user = request()->input('user');

    $first_name = request()->input('first_name');
    $last_name = request()->input('last_name');

    $validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
      'firstName'                     => 'required|alpha',
      'lastName'                      => 'required|alpha'
    ], [
      'firstName.required'            => 'You need to give a first name!',
      'firstName.alpha'               => 'A first name can only contain letters!',
      'lastName.required'             => 'You need to give a last name!',
      'lastName.alpha'                => 'A last name can only contain letters!'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {

      return response()->json($validator, 404);

    }

    $employees->editUser($user, $first_name, $last_name);

    return response()->json($user);

}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you had updated your previous question. As well replied to people that tried to help you.

Comment: I'll admit, it felt a bit weird responding because my eventual solution was very off the mark from what was suggested. Still, that's a fair point to make. The previous question has been edited with a redirect to here.

Answer (score 0):

So I realized the issue was twofold. First, what I was trying to return when the validator failed was incorrect. Rather than simply passing the whole validator, I needed to simply pass its messages, like so:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {

  return response()->json($validator->messages(), 404);

}
```

The second issue actually had to do with calling "request()->all()". I had assumed the array obtained would have worked, but for some reason it didn't. When I created a new array based on the values in "request()" it was able to get the validator results I was expecting.